# Hololens emulator -DEP6957: Failed to connect to device 'xxx' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode

Tags: visual-studio, hololens, windows-mixed-reality, hololens-emulator

I am trying to install Hololens emulator.

I successfully installed and run demo application on my home PC.
However, I am trying to have it working of my business laptop where work should actually be done.
I installed VS 2022 17.4 and all Windows SDK available, and also all workloads needed.
I use Unity 2020.3 as it is recommended and I installed multiple Hololens emulators.
One old works by I get authentication error so app cannot be deployed.
On emulator 10.0.20348.1528 I get this error:

The emulator is unable to verify that virtual machine is running.

Failed to find the required partition 'MainOS' on the mounted virtual disk

**Edit:**

**Please ignore error message above. I installed just a little older version of emulator and emulator now works. Now problem is with deploying from Visual Studio.**

I visited https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/hololens-emulator-archive and installed HoloLens 2 Emulator build 10.0.20348.**1518** (so not latest 10.0.20348.**1528**) and emulator is now starting but I get deploy error:

```
DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '192.168.191.217' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. DllNotFoundException - Unable to load DLL 'SirepClient.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F) [0x80131524]
```

Details:

```
ConnectTo-Device: END (Failure, 0:00:00.034)
BootstrapAsync-Deploying: END (Failure, 0:00:00.037)
Deploy: START
    Bootstrapping.Target = PII(3a4e6275-4097-a054-94dd-e12793d099f0)
    Target.DeviceGuid = 3a4e6275-4097-a054-94dd-e12793d099f0
    Target.MemorySize = 4096
    Target.EmulatorName = HoloLens 2 Emulator 10.0.20348.1518
    BootstrappingSucceed = False
    BootstrappingError = Err_SSHBootstrapping_ConnectedDevice_FailedToConnect
    BootstrappingHResult = -2146233088
    DeploymentSucceeded = False
    Target.Id = 1280
    ProjectGuid = {2fabdf39-a3a3-4497-95ba-5aee089ebf0f}
    Project.TargetPlatformVersion = 10.0.22621.0
    Project.TargetPlatformMinVersion = 10.0.10240.0
Deploy: END (Failure, 0:00:00.001)
```

Inside deployment view inside Visual Studio I can see logs that everything emulator needs is enabled (like Hyper-V) otherwise emulator wouldn't event start. Once again emulator starts this time but deployment fails.

```
ConfigurationParser/Constructor/EnumerateEmulators: END (Success, 0:00:00.483)
ConfigurationParser/Constructor: END (Success, 0:00:00.598)
IsEmulatorSupported: START
    Is64BitOperatingSystem = True
DetectSlat: START
    isHyperVRunning = True
DetectSlat: END (Success, 0:00:00.109)
    SlatState = SlatAndHWVEnabled
    IsEmulatorSupported = True
IsEmulatorSupported: END (Success, 0:00:00.117)
```

My Windows version is 1909 (unable to upgrade because some error) but on home PC it is 21H2. That seems the only difference to me.

This is screenshoot of Project-> Properties-> Configuration Properties-> Debugging (I think emulator is selected here, not remote device so error message is misleading)
[image]

EDIT and solution:

I fixed it by updating Windows to 22H2 (was very challenging) to update since there was update error constantly showing up but I did it using Windows Update Assistant and by downloading Windows to USB)

After that I installed Unity 2020.3.2F1 and VS 2022 17.4.

This emulator experience is by the way terrible, not only regarding downloading but with running it and using it.

Comment: Does your PC have developer mode turned on? Have you tried opening the emulator directly instead of opening it through Visual Studio? If you can't open it, would you also try to run as administrator? Then check if the emulator has developer mode and Device discovery enabled.

Comment: Yes, emulator is starting. But now I get error while trying to deploy. DEP6957: Failed to connect to device '192.168.191.217' using Universal Authentication. Please verify the correct remote authentication mode is specified in the project debug settings. DllNotFoundException - Unable to load DLL 'SirepClient.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F) [0x80131524] which is strange because I'm not trying to deploy to device but to emulator and in Visual Studio Emulator is selected, not device. Developer mode is turned on.

Comment: We will dig into this issue, but if it is urgent, you can try to install the application via the Device Portal of the emulator. Please refer to [Packaging MSIX apps - MSIX | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/package/packaging-uwp-apps#create-an-app-package-using-the-packaging-wizard) to package the application and then refer to [Using the Windows Device Portal - Mixed Reality | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/mixed-reality/develop/advanced-concepts/using-the-windows-device-portal#sideloading-applications) to install it.

Comment: Also, can you provide a screenshot of Project-> Properties-> Configuration Properties-> Debugging?

Comment: Ok, I will. I finally managed to update Windows and installing VS and Unity again. Can this problem be because emulator is unable to connect to internet?

Comment: Fixed by updating Windows (very challenging to update from 9009 to 22H2. Had to use Windows Update Assistant, and download windows to USB and delete some empty 0kb "ini" file. Downloading, running and using this emulator is horrible experience !